# no conda.exe -- need help installing anaconda properly on ms windows 10

Tags: anaconda

I am encountering issues when installing anaconda 5.1.0 64-bit python 2.7 on windows10.

Q&A in the Setup dialog: There are two questions (1) I did not checkbox "add anaconda to my PATH env variable" because it is discouraged. (2) I also did not checkbox "register anaconda as my default python 2.7" because this might mess up my existing processes/scripts.

After this, it installs and declares victory; "anaconda prompt" shows up in start menu but that's about it. It opens a command prompt with

```
'C:\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Will appreciate help in getting this install right. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're installing Anaconda with Python 2.7? The command prompt (`'C:\Anaconda3...`) implies that you're installing with Python 3. Do you have an old install of Anaconda still hanging around?

Comment: that was a sharp observation! I found an older py 3 variant. But even after uninstalling that and then reinstalling Anaconda for 2.7, I get the same message (with correct dir name)

Comment: Is Anaconda actually installed in that directory? i.e., did you install as Administrator/"root"?

Comment: No, it was "just for me" option.

Comment: Then that's not the correct installation directory, which is why it can't find the script. I don't know why it's looking there. You should make sure there are no registry settings, no old shortcuts, no configuration files, etc. leftover from old installs.

Comment: I cleaned up all prior installs, dirs, checked registry, rebooted, and reinstalled -- but no luck. It's broken, there is no "activate.bat" to be found. I suspect it's a buggy install package :-( but thanks for your help